# Swing GridBagLayout - created empty space by adding components

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I'm having trouble understanding where the additinoal space comes from after I added a few components.

My layout has two rows (containing some controls) at top, and a large image pane. So far, I could create my desired look using gridwidth (aka colspan).

After adding two new buttons in my first row and adapting some of the gridwidths, my window became wider and I have some additional empty space of which I do not know at all where it comes from. I have already played around with the weights and some more gridwidths, but no success.

**Edit:** I also tried to reproduce it with some minimal code, but that never showed the problem.

My project is called OpenSourceCaptchaSolver, and it can be used for earning credits on captcha exchange sites. Source code and IntelliJ IDEA project files (Community edition will do) are available at sourceforge:

```
git clone git://git.code.sf.net/p/opensourcecaptchasolver/code OpenSourceCaptchaSolver
```

In order to make my changes reproducible, I have created two branches:

- stackoverflow-swing-layout-before
- stackoverflow-swing-layout-changed

If you check out the code and switch between these branches, you can easily see what I changed and how it looks like.
Normally, you need an account on 9kw.eu for runnning the program (at the moment, this is the only supported captcha exchange site). I have added a dummy account ID and commented out a few things to make it runnable without, just for looking at the layout. Of course, it is not functional this way.
Main class to run is *opensourcecaptchasolver.gui.Main*

**Edit:** I know that many people do not have the time to look at a large project and read all the code, but this is a rather small project and the difference between the branches I listed above is only 8 lines.

As soon as I have the required 10 reputation, I will post some screenshots. Unfortunately, I don't think I can demonstrate my problem with character graphics in between ...

Comment: Many folks don't have the desire (too lazy or too paranoid), or the capability (work/school firewalls) to download code from an unknown source. For better help sooner, please post a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem. Many times, just creating the example will reveal the problem.

Comment: Yes, that's what I tried also. Maybe I should add this to my question. With a minimal code, I could not reproduce the problem.

Comment: Well then, your problem lies elsewhere. Keep expanding your minimal code example, gradually, to match your existing code until you find the problem.

Comment: I think it must be the combination of my components and gridbag constraints. But if I remove some components or if I build up my layout step-by-step (and even if the empty space disappearst after that), it's still try-and-error and that doesn't give me the understanding which principle I violated. My hope is for somebody with a little time (maybe a student) who looks at the code and my error pops into his eyes right away.